# Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow not working in STS 3.6.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

The keyboard shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

is not working in STS 3.6.2.RELEASE.

Please note: I have already disabled the graphics card hot keys.

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: See the following post if it helps: [Copy-Lines Shortcut Problem(ctrl+alt+down is not working) ](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368780/)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem. It turned out that my OS (Ubuntu) already used that key-binding. After redefining that one Ctr+Alt+Down worked again.